# Why is $\pi$ irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

I've a few questions in mind:

- Why is $\pi$ irrational?
- If it is, then how can 2 rational quantities (circumference, diameter) can produce irrational number?
- How are we able to determine digits of $\pi$ accurately?

Comment: The diameter of the unit circle is indeed rational.  Now, what makes you think the circumference is also rational?

Comment: Because if you cut the circle (theoretically) and stretch it out, it becomes a line, which is indeed rational. (I think)

Comment: @MehulMohan: If you agree that there do **exist** irrational numbers, then obviously you can have lines whose length is an irrational number.

Comment: There you go : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational

Comment: See [Approximations of $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80)

Comment: The diagonal of the unit square is already a straight line, no stretching required, and has irrational length by the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Okay I do agree that irrational lengths exists. But for example, if I take a square with side 4cm and stretch it theoretically to make it a circle, what would happen?

Comment: If you think the diameter and circumference of a circle are "two rational quantities" then I start to wonder if the meaning of "rational number" is clear in your mind. As to your third question, see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297/simple-numerical-methods-for-calculating-the-digits-of-pi ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MehulMohan : Then you get a circle whose circumference is $16$ centimeters and whose diameter is $16/\pi$ centimeters. The latter is an irrational number of centimeters. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MehulMohan if a circle has circumference $C$ and diameter $D$, then we define $\pi := \frac{C}{D}$. Since it is known that $\pi$ is irrational (see the list of proofs posted above), we conclude that $C$ and $D$ cannot both be rational.

Comment: So you all are saying that technically, I can never split a circle's circumference into equal parts with each part equal to radius of that circle? Or more precisely if I start with any point on circumference and then jump the distance equal to radius, on circumference, I'd never come back to my original position? Interesting!

Comment: The problem is not that ... the issue is that, whatever the lenght ot your jump is, **provided that** is a finite fraction of the radius, you will never succeed.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: the circumference is $\mathbf{2}\pi r$ so you need $7$ jumps to get past the starting point.

Comment: 2 rational numbers CANT produce a irrational number. I found a good proof of the irrationality here. http://worldpifederation.org/Fed/irrational.pdf

Comment: Part 2 of the question was asked earlier here: [Why is π
irrational if it is represented as C/D
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184675/why-is-pi-irrational-if-it-is-represented-as-c-d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name "irrational number" has an ancient source...

It was an (implicit) assumption common to all "archaic" Greek mathematics that given two magnitudes, e.g. to segments of lenght $a$ and $b$, it is always possible to find a segment of "unit lenght" $u$ such that it *measure* both, i.e. such that [using modern algebraic formulae which are totally foreign to Greek math] :

> $a = n \times u$ and $b = m \times u$, for $n,m \in \mathbb N$.

From the above instance of the assumption, it follows that :

> $a/b = (n \times u) / (m \times u) = n/m$.

The assumption amounts to saying that the ratio between two magnitudes is always a ratio between *numbers* (i.e. in modern terms : a *rational* number; but note that for Greek math the **only** numbers are the *natural* ones and they are distinguished from *magnitudes* : a segment, a square, ... which are "measured" by numbers).

The discovery of the existence of [irrational magnitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#cite_note-8), through the proof that the case where $a=1$ is the side of the unit square and $b=\sqrt 2$ is the diagonal is not expressible as a ratio between (natural) numbers, leads Greek math to the withdrawal of the "commensurability assumption" and to the axiomatization of geometry.

Those couples of magnitudes was called "incommensurable" (i.e. without common *measure*).

For the same reason, $\sqrt 2$ is an *irrational* number, exactly because the *ratio* "diagonal/side" is not expressible as a ratio between natural numbers.

---

The *irrationality* of $\pi$ was [proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational) by [Johann Heinrich Lambert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Heinrich_Lambert) in [1761](https://www.bibnum.education.fr/mathematiques/theorie-des-nombres/lambert-et-l-irrationalite-de-p-1761).