# Why is pi irrational number?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

I know $\pi$ is 3.141592653589793......
We all learn this at school.

But I haven't learned why pi is irrational number.

How can prove that pi is irrational number?

I would be grateful if you can explain it easily.  :)

Maybe I didn't understand it, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432540/why-is-pi-irrational) didn't help me anyway.

Comment: Yes, the answer doesn't answer anything, but did you follow the link that says "[proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational)" in the answer?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for.  Do you want why we know $\pi$ is irrational, which a proof would answer, or some reason that it "should be" irrational?  There are so many more irrationals than rationals that any number that doesn't "have to be" rational isn't.

Comment: Why not, there are provably more irrational than rational numbers. If $\pi$ is  rational or even algebraic, then it will be a big surprise.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The content was difficult, but it was answered. I did not see the wiki content when I searched because I am not an English speaker.

Comment: "Mathologer" has a proof on YouTube that you might find interesting.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lk_QF_hcM8A

Comment: Irrationality proofs are usually extremely difficult. For example, whether $e+\pi$ or whether $e\cdot \pi$ is irrational, is not known. The argument that "almost every real number is irrational" is the common answer to such questions if a number has "no obvious reason" to be rational or at least algebraic. Irrationality is assumed for the Euler-Mascheroni-constant, but again the character of this number is unknown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $\pi$ irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432540/why-is-pi-irrational)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But it's still not easy to understand.
okay. I see why root 2 is an irrational number. I am not sure how this affects my question. Maybe it's because my English isn't good...